# mean line for temporal sequence ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to add a line that put in relation the mean of 3 values per year over the year.

Ex:

```
Year  Month  Density
2004   06     5
2004   07     6
2004   08     4
2005   06     0.5
2005   07     1.2
2005   08     4.3
2006   06     5.4
...
```

So far I have this code:

`enter code here`Data$Date<-paste(Data$Annee, Data$Month,01, sep="-")
`enter code here`Data$Date <- as.Date(Data$Date, format = "%Y-%m-%d")

```
ggplot(Data, aes(Date, Densite, group=Month))+ylab("Density (N/ha)")+ xlab("Year") +   geom_point(stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") + stat_summary_bin(aes(y = Densite), fun.y = "mean", geom = "bar")
```

But it dosen't work, it makes a line for each group...I want one value per year and the line that connect those mean per year.

Hope it's clear :)

Nico

Thanks

Comment: I would recommend creating a data frame of the values you want to plot rather than relying on ggplot to do the aggregating for you. That said, you *might* have luck if you get rid of the `group = Month` or move it to the `geom_point` layer. You might need a `group = 1` in the stat_summary layer... it very hard to tell what data types you are using. If you share your data with `dput()` all will be clear.

Comment: Very nice ! it worked when I moved it to the geom_point layer :

ggplot(Data, aes(Date, Densite))+ylab("Density (N/ha)")+ xlab("Year") +   geom_point(aes(group=Month),stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3")+  stat_summary_bin(aes(y = Densite), fun.y = "mean", geom = "line")

Comment: Glad it worked. Next time please use `dput()` to share your data.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer , thanks to @Gregor

```
ggplot(HUM, aes(Date, Densite))+ylab("Density (N/ha)")+ xlab("Year") +   geom_point(aes(group=Month),stat="identity", position = "dodge") + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3")+ scale_fill_discrete(guide=FALSE)+  stat_summary_bin(aes(y = Densite), fun.y = "mean", geom = "line")
```